# Visual Studio Online Build failing on TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, msbuild, tsc

I am building my project on a Visual Studio online HOsted server which says it it is running an older version:

```
PreComputeCompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe has TypeScript 2.0.6 installed.
```

When I attempt to build, I get build errors which I believe are being caused as --project "d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\Portal\tsconfig.json"
    CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe --project "d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\Portal\tsconfig.json"
    ##[error]VSTSC(0,0): Error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'.
    VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'baseUrl'. [d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\MyProject.csproj]
    ##[error]VSTSC(0,0): Error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'paths'.
    VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'paths'. [d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\MyProject.csproj]
    ##[error]VSTSC(0,0): Error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots'.
    VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots'. [d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\MyProject.csproj]
    Done Building Project "d:_work\9\s\Main\SRC\MyProject.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
    Done Building Project "d:_work\9\s\Main\Solutions\MyProject.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

I have a specified

> `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>`

In my project file, but it doesn't seem to be recognized.  What am I missing to force the newwer TS version to run?  Is this being caused by something else possibly?

UPDATE:
It appears I can downgrade to 1.7 and it will recognize (but break obviously), but it will not use 2.0 - which would indicate that it is not installed on the Hosted machine.  After setting the build command manually to

I then get the error

> ### [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(165,5):
>
> Error : Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript
>   compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No
>   compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\2.0\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by
>   changing the  element in your project file.

But according to this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software - it should be installed (using Visual Studio 15), correct?

Comment: Check PATH environment variable. It should point to 2.0 typescript folder and not 1.8. If you don't have 2.0 at path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\ then install Typescript for Visual studio 2015

Comment: This is the MS VSO *hosted* build server, so I cannot do anything to it, but according to this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software  it should be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test result is the same to you, it still uses 1.8.

Refer to these steps to deal with this issue:

1. Add/Install [Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/) to your project
2. Edit your project file (.csproj)

   a.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's props file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.props')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />-->
   ```

   b.) Configure MSBuild to use the NuGet package's targets file.

   ```
   <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.0.6\build\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.targets')" />
   <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />-->
   ```

   If it is .Net Core project, add this code to  section of .xproj file

   ```
   <TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0.6</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
   <TscToolPath>C:\Users\[user account]\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild\2.0.6\tools\tsc</TscToolPath>
   ```

Comment: This worked great - should the documentation here be updated to reflect that 2.0 is *not* installed on the hosted machines, that caused a lot of confusion. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/hosted-pool#software